# Cleaning up a CW question with 43 answers

Tags: discussion, clean-up

The question: ["The breakpoint will not currently be hit. The source code is different from the original version." What does this mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2468852/247702)

There are a lot of possible causes and solutions, but having read most of the answers after encountering the issue myself, I feel there's at least some duplicate information spread between the 43 answers.

Some of them also have noise that makes it harder to read the answer, like "X, Y and Z didn't work for me" or "I spent X hours on this" and bad formatting in general. With this many possible solutions it's more pleasant to just be able to see the actual answer instead of having to read each one carefully to see which part of the answer contains the actual solution.

Any idea how this (very useful) question can be cleaned up a bit? Should every answer be edited separately, or should we perhaps compile the most common causes in a single CW answer?

Comment: Start with a voting spree?

Comment: I casted a delete vote on answers that went into negative. I won't downvote others, I don't know much about .NET. Keep downvoting and I will help with deletion.

Comment: It seems that the question is off-topic for the reason: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example._

Comment: @devnull Most of the time the problem is unrelated to a specific piece of code. It can suddenly appear and suddenly disappear. Examples would be useless.

Comment: Fair enough.  Even then it would be off-topic or "too broad".  An answer that requires one to enumerate all possible reasons due to which a breakpoint might not be hit doesn't make it a very good question.  It would appear more appropriate as a bug report for the IDE or whatever in question.

Comment: @devnull tools used for development are on-topic for SO, so if that is a common issue, I see it being a good question even if there are multiple answers

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Wow, that question turned into a circus. I applaud you for wanting to clean it up.

A lot of those answers are bad, some are downright wrong. The appropriate action is to **down vote** the bad or wrong answers, once they go sufficiently negative they should become deletable by trusted users. There is no point editing some of the answers - once you remove the superfluous crap there is no answer left, therefore it should go.

Bear in mind that Stack Overflow was considerably different back when those answers were left, clearly people got away with conversational, anecdotal and waffley answers.

If you are going to edit, concentrate your efforts on the higher voted or more respectable answers. I wouldn't be flagging them as *Not an answer*, as that will put a flag in the moderator queue and they will rightfully dismiss it as unhelpful (it will be a race condition as to whether the moderators clear it first or the VLQ queue reviewers do).

Comment: I don't mind downvoting one or two answers. Unfortunately downvoting 20 answers really adds up and moreover eats away my votes that I can use that day.

Comment: @skiwi The job is almost done - there are only a few answers left that deserve to be removed.

Comment: I thought I'd wait a bit to see how this Meta discussion turned out to take action but it seems that the community has already taken care of it. Nice work :)

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to see the answers being edited separately and **not** combined. As you said yourself, there are many different solutions.

Keeping them separate allows the most common solutions to rise to the top, and makes it much easier to read.

---

The workflow I'd propose would therefore be to edit each answer individually, and remove the cruft as you suggested.

If you notice a duplicate answer, flag one of them (lowest voted/ least clear) for moderator attention, and ask for it to be deleted, because it's a duplicate.

Comment: Well i agree with your first point. But your last sentence is just wrong in my opinion. A dublicate isn't about beeing lower voted or least clear but about beeing published later than the "original". Thus if there has been a amount of time between the answers you should delete that which came later and as you said edit the other to make it readible. Also in most cases even to similar answers yield different informations for future visitors, so it could be better to leave both answers (except one is truly malicious)

Comment: @TheMinion: A duplicate is ***not*** determined by age. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204723/163863). As this CW question is effectively a "list" (of solutions), we're certainly not bothered about which answer was posted first; we want the one that has helped the community most to be the "canonical" one. For two *similar* answers; it totally depends on *how* similar. In some cases, editing one of them to contain *all* information would be better, in others this would be too much work, and leaving them separate would be the best option.